# Missing ref owner context in production

Tags: vue.js

I'm using VueJS 3 in options API and while the application works locally, it does not work well in the shared hosting (when built).

The warning is thrown in the console:

> [Vue warn]: Missing ref owner context. ref cannot be used on hoisted vnodes. A vnode with ref must be created inside the render function.

It happens just in this variable: `let items = ref([]);` and only when app is build with `npm run build` - it does not happen when doing `npm run dev`.

Code:

```
<script setup>
let items = ref([]);

function addItem() {
items.value.unshift({...});
}
</script>
```

And inside template - I use to render the items using `v-for`:

```
<template>
 <tbody v-if="items.length > 0">
    <tr v-for="(i, idx) in items" :key="i.id">
      <td class="text-center" ref="anchorId + {{ idx }}"> {{ idx+1 }} </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</template>
```

Now, I have a button that basically calls `addItem()`, and when an item is added by `unshift()`, it would be displayed in the table - reactively. However, doing so will throw the aforementioned warning.

Comment: Where are you calling `ref`?

Comment: @shim I'm calling it as: `<tbody v-if="items.length > 0"><tr v-for="(i, idx) in items" :key="i.id">` in the template.

Comment: Don't see `ref` in there. Are you calling it inside `setup`?

Comment: @shim I have added some code, hopefully omitting trivial blocks. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add the index to the ref name inside your `v-for`, if you have defined the `const` as:

```
const elementsRefs = ref([]);
```

Your loop can be like

```
<tr v-for="(i, idx) in items" :key="i.id">
  <td class="text-center" ref="elementsRefs"> {{ idx+1 }} </td>
</tr>
```

And then you can access `elementsRefs` as an array of `HTMLElements`

Documentation: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs#refs-inside-v-for

Please note is better to use `const`, because you are not going to replace the entire variable, but manipulate its contents

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue while migrating from Vue 2 to Vue 3. I had a ref that sometimes evaluated to `false`:

```html
<MyComponent
  :ref="index === 0 ? 'first' : false"
>
```

Vue 3 apparently doesn't like that. In my prod bundle that failed with:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading ‘refs’)

(That error is thrown a couple lines below the "Missing ref owner context" warning from the original question, which happens in dev builds.)

You can fix this by refactoring the ref to always be a string (or, in my case, I removed the ref completely).